# batch, setting a string variable in a for loop

Tags: string, batch-file, for-loop, set, echo

When inside a for loop, the set command doesn't set the string variable, whereas outside it works fine. I would like it to export to a .txt file directly after storing, and that works fine. Here is the code:

```
For /l %%a in (1,1,5) do (
set /p string="StringIn %%a:"
echo %string %>> string_list.txt
)

Start string_list.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

When expanding variables set within parentheses scope you need to use delayed expansion.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /l %%a in (1,1,5) do (
    set /p string="StringIn %%a:"
    >> string_list.txt echo !string!
)
endlocal
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked well (and will be good knowledge for the future), but I'm using this code for folder comparison, and I found a more efficient means by using DIR and exporting the subfolders to a text document. Do you know if there is a way to format the command or output so I have only the folder name and not all the other data? This kind of deviates from the original question, so I don't know if I should ask a new question?

Comment: Use the '/b' option for only the file path and name with the '/ad' option to only list directories with the dir command. See 'dir /?' for all the options.